# visualizing high dimension data in matplotlib/python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, data-visualization

I am trying to use Gaussian Processes for fitting smooth functions to some datapoints. I am using `scikit-learn` library for python and in my case my input are two dimensional spatial coordinates and the output are some transformed version and also 2-D spatial coordinates. I generated some dummy test data and tried to fit a GP model to it. The code that I used was as follows:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel as C
import numpy as np

# Some dummy data
X = np.random.rand(10, 2)
Y = np.sin(X)

# Use the squared exponential kernel
kernel = C(1.0, (1e-3, 1e3)) * RBF(10, (1e-2, 1e2))
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=9)
# Fit to data using Maximum Likelihood Estimation of the parameters
gp.fit(X, Y)
print(X)
# Evaluate on a test point
test = np.random.rand(1, 2)
test[:, 0] = 1.56
test[:, 1] = 0.92
y_pred, sigma = gp.predict(test, return_std=True)
print(test, np.sin(test))  # The true value
print(y_pred, sigma)  # The predicted value and the STD
```

I was wondering if there is a good way to visualize the model fit. As my input and output dimensions are both 2-D, I am not sure how I can visualize it quickly so that I get an idea of the model fit (particularly want to know the smoothness and variance of the model prediction between the points). Most examples online are, of course, for 1-D case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you need is [Principal Component Analysis(PCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) which is a statistical technique to reduce the dimension of a dataset while preserving their variance in the high dimension to the low dimension.

In python :

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca_x=PCA(n_components=1)
X1D=pca.fit_transform(X)

pca_y=PCA(n_components=1)
y1D=pca.fit_transform(y)

plt.plot(X1D,y1D)
```

**n_components=d** where **d** is the required reduced dimension

link to PCA in sklearn -->[here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)

An alternative could be **t-distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding** in short **[t-sne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding)** which is also used to visualize high dimensional data, find python implementation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html)

Comment: That is a good idea. I am going to try this. Thank you. I guess I can saample the function at many points and then do the PCA. I will give it a shot.

Comment: @Luca I have also added another solution **t-sne**, have a look